# Spring MVC: Load jars to classpath from external folder along with WEB-INF\lib

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, classpath

I have a Spring MVC Application(with Maven) that will be deployed to the tomcat server. All its libs goes to WEB-INF\lib.

I have a custom jar which contains spring services, i want to load this to classpath from external folder. This custom jar may not present all times. If it copy it to WEB-INF\lib manually, it works. But, that is not an ideal solution as new war deployment will erase this jar.

I have tried setting its path in setenv.sh using CLASSPATH, but the Autowired classes in the internal classes are not working.

Is there any way we can set the external folder as classpath along with WEB-INF\lib?

Any help would be appreciated.